# Dynamically modifying fields in django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django

Okay so I have two classes one is Book and the other one is Category. Book and Category are linked by a foreign key named category which is a Book field.
See the code

```
class Category(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"

    category = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category


class Book(models.Model):
    book_title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.book_title
```

And below are the serializer classes

```
class DynamicFieldsModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    A ModelSerializer that takes an additional `fields` argument that
    controls which fields should be displayed.
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Don't pass the 'fields' arg up to the superclass
        fields = kwargs.pop('fields', None)

        # Instantiate the superclass normally
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if fields is not None:
            # Drop any fields that are not specified in the `fields` argument.
            allowed = set(fields)
            existing = set(self.fields)
            for field_name in existing - allowed:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)


class CategorySerializer(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        # only show the category field 
        fields = ['category']

class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # this will show the category data which is related to this Book
    category = CategorySerializer()
    class Meta: 
        model = Book
        fields = '__all__'
```

And now I want that when I get the data of the book using @api_view, I should only get the category name, which I am getting no problem at all but when I want to see the data of Category then want to see the all fields. but it shows nothing.
Code of @api_view

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def getBooks(request):
    books = Book.objects.all()
    serilized_data = BookSerializer(books,many=True)
    return Response({'status': 200, 'payload': serilized_data.data})


# it is now only show the category as only category field is passed in CategorySerilizer
@api_view(['GET'])
def getCategory(request):
    category = Category.objects.all()
    serilized_data = CategorySerializer(category,fields = ('__all__'),many=True)
    return Response({'status': 200, 'payload': serilized_data.data})
```

And the output of getCategory is

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "payload": [
        {},
        {}
    ]
}
```

And one more thing to notice is I have only 2 categories inside my database which is also shown by it via {}, {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to nest your serializers to get the outcome you want. You could change your serializers like this:

```py
    class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Category 
            fields = '__all__'
    
    class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        # Now your only getting the name of the category without having to nest the serializers
        category = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="category.category")
    
        class Meta: 
            model = Book
            fields = '__all__'
```

And then you would need to remove the fields=('__all'__) when you call the serializer in the view.

Comment: We can also remove  DynamicFieldsModelSerializer class. It won't affect what we want. Thanks

Comment: can you explain why it category.category as category is field name, I thought it should be Category.category but I was wrong.

Comment: Ah, thanks @Kanha Tomar! I edited the answer to use ModelSerializer now. The field name is category.category because it is seen from the "point of view" of the Book model. We are not referring to the model named Category, but rather the field named "category" on the Book model. Hope that clears it up :)

Comment: Got it. It's like related name.

Answer (score 0):

In the getCategory function, change the serilized_data to `serilized_data = CategorySerializer(category,many=True)`

Comment: Then it will show the fields which are written in CategorySerializer class fields. Don't fullfill our moto.